# How to create single link which will open random link from multiple link

Tags: javascript, url

I have 5 different website links.
Of the five links, I want to make 1 link which when I click on the link it will automatically open 1 particular website out of 5 website links that I have.
I've tried using the script, but I don't know how to create a link from the script.

The script opens the link in a new tab. But to do that I have to include the script in the web page and other people have to open the web page first before they can click the script button. What I want is to create a link so I can pass it on to others without having to open the website first

Can anyone provide a solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "a.com";
urls[1] = "b.com";
urls[2] = "c.com";
urls[3] = "d.com";
urls[4] = "e.com";
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
window.location = urls[random];
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: So...what exactly happens right now when you run this code?

Comment: The script opens the link in a new tab. But to do that I have to include the script in the web page and other people have to open the web page first before they can click the script button.

What I want is to create a link so I can pass it on to others without having to open the website first.

Comment: In that case, maybe have a "page" which consists of nothing except this script, then the user won't actually see anything when they click on the link, before they are redirected to the random link. Or use PHP to implement this so it's all done server side, as suggested below

Comment: P.s. it's not really clear what you mean by `people have to open the web page first before they can click the script button`...the script you've shown should run as soon as the page arrives in the browser, without any user intervention. No buttons are involved. What button are you referring to?

Comment: Also `The script opens the link in a new tab`...the code you've provided doesn't do that. window.location redirects the current window. There is a way to open in a new tab but you're code isn't doing it

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I'm new to this so it took some time to get my point across and understand your answer. I'm trying the instructions you gave. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only pass a link, you need to create a web server that you can give the link to and the web server will redirect to one of those links.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try the instructions you gave. Thank you again